# What is the advantage of remove() method in traditional collection and concurrent collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I know the underlying difference between the `remove()` method of the traditional collection like `hashMap` and concurrent collection like `concurrentHashMap`. In `concurrentHashmap`, JVM will match the key and the value both before removing the key value object which is required for the multithreading environment. 
Is there any other difference between them?

Comment: No, there isn't.  (Unless you are thinking of something specifically as a "difference" that I wouldn't think of as a difference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking why is there a second `remove` method in the concurrent map.

`Map` has:

```
V remove​(Object key)
```

`ConcurrentMap` has an *additional* method:

```
boolean remove​(Object key, Object value)
```

(In fact, `Map` has this as a default method since 1.8.)

In a non-concurrent `Map`, the two-arg form can easily written by composing a `get` followed by `remove`, at the cost of two lookups. Concurrent operations, however, do not compose. For concurrent maps you may see `remove` used in a loop similar to how `compareAndSet` is typically used.

You could perform the remove operation in a single operation through the normal collections interfaces if you first used `entrySet`. It's just not very convenient or obvious.